# tweaking utility for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, performance

I am using windows 7 and I need a tweaking utility compatible with Windows 7.

Comment: Optimizing for what?

Comment: @Ivo This is not a real question. Also it's subjective. These best-of questions that keep popping up really should be better dealt with.

Comment: Per request I closed it while you were typing it

Comment: Edited it, so now it's a real question.

Comment: Here you are @harrymc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is about tweaking Windows 7, then look at the following free products:

[TweakNow](http://www.tweaknow.com/)
[TweakVI](http://www.totalidea.com/product.php?Product=TweakVI)

Answer (score 1):

[7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) has some useful features:

[image: 7 Taskbar Tweaker]

Answer (score 1):

Ultimate Windows Tweaker

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-v2-a-tweak-ui-for-windows-7-vista#more-1957

Driver tweaker

http://www.slimdrivers.com/

Windows size tweaker

http://www.nattyware.com/feewhee.php

DNS tweaker, speed up internet page loads for any browser

http://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Context Menu tweaker

http://www.sdsoftware.org/default.asp?id=11403

7 Plus

http://code.google.com/p/7plus/wiki/Features

Fix Win

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-fix-windows-7-vista-problems-with-fixwin-utility

Q Dir

http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir

Start Menu 7

http://www.startmenu7.com/index.html

System Nucleus

http://www.spencerberus.com/projects.aspx

Vista Switcher, work with XP-W7

http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html

Windows 7 taskbar pinner

http://www.door2windows.com/windows-7-taskbar-items-pinner-pin-files-folders-to-your-windows-7-taskbar/

X Mouse

http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

Aero Tuner

http://hb860.deviantart.com/art/AeroTuner-183456299

.

Comment: I think you deserve an upvote for that lot.

Comment: Finally, someone noticed!